# Cauchy product of multivariate formal power series

Tags: ring-theory, power-series, convolution, formal-power-series

Cauchy product of two univariate formal power series is pretty straight forward. If

$$A=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i \, ,$$
and
$$B=\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j x^j \, ,$$
then 
$$A \times B = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{l=0}^k a_l b_{k-l} \right)x^k \, ,$$

where $\times$ is the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

How can we calculate the Cauchy product of two multivariate infinite power series of the form:

$$\Phi=\sum_{i_1=0}^\infty \ldots \sum_{i_n=0}^\infty \phi_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}\prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{i_j} \, .$$

**P.S.**

I will try to answer my question here, maybe it will help to understand the form of solution I'm looking for. Consider $\boldsymbol{\phi}_{p_1,\ldots,p_n}$ and $\boldsymbol{\psi}_{q_1,\ldots,q_n}$ to be n dimensional arrays (consider NumPy's `ndarray`s for example). Also consider the operators

1. $\boldsymbol{\phi}^F$ to be a flipped version of $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ in all directions from 1 to n.
2. $\langle \boldsymbol{\phi}, \boldsymbol{\psi} \rangle_\mathrm{F}$ is the Frobenius inner product of two nD arrays of the same shape
3. $\left\{ \boldsymbol{\phi} \right\}_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}$ is a slice of the nD array from ${0,\ldots,0}$ to ${k_1,\ldots,k_n}$

then

$$\Omega=\Phi \times \Psi \equiv \boldsymbol{\omega}$$

I think the solution be of the form:

$$\omega_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}=\langle \left\{ \boldsymbol{\phi'} \right\}_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}, \left\{ \left\{ \boldsymbol{\psi'} \right\}_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}\right\}^F \rangle_\mathrm{F}\, , \, \, 0\leq k_j \leq o_j=p_j+q_j-1 $$

Comment: If you have found an answer to your question, [post it as an answer, not an edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I'm working on it. I'm testing it over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782224/populating-a-numpy-ndarray-of-an-arbitrary-shape-preferably-without-using-for-l) I will mwrite an answer as soon as I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $\Phi_1$ has $m$ multivariate terms while $\Phi_2$ has $n$ multivariate terms, let

$$A_p = \left\{(i_1,\ldots, i_m,j_1,\ldots, j_n) \in \mathbb{N}^{m+n} \mid \sum_{k=1}^m i_k + \sum_{k=1}^n j_k = p\right\}$$

This would be the set of all $m+n$-tuples that add up to $p$ where each component is at least zero (basically, the set of all integral solutions to the associated Diophantine equation).

Then, the product:

$$\Phi_1\times \Phi_2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{(i_1,\ldots, i_m,j_1,\ldots, j_n)\in A_k}\phi_{i_1,\ldots, i_m}\phi_{j_1,\ldots, j_n}x^k$$

Edit: Actually, there is no reason to do this the way I was trying to do it. I can use your original notation and it should work fine.

$$\sum_{i_1=0}^\infty\cdots \sum_{i_n=0}^\infty \sum_{j_1=0}^\infty \cdots \sum_{j_n=0}^\infty \phi_{i_1,\ldots, i_n}\psi_{j_1,\ldots, j_n}\prod_{k=1}^n x^{i_k+j_k}$$

Comment: The power series have same number of variables. I also added a **P.S.**. Would appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: Let me explain it this way: Both your solution and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2877497/328278) define a set, but you do not provide a method for finding that set. Something which later can be implemented with conventional programing language for example. Consider NumPy for example. Can you write your solution there?

Comment: I added more information to the **P.S.**. I would appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: @Foad I actually think I was overthinking things. I just updated my answer. Based on your original notation, we can just sum over both sets of indices and it will be the correct answer. I was thinking too hard about combining like terms (getting all of the $x^k$ terms together).

Comment: Thanks a lot. your solution seems practically OK now, hence the upvote. I'm hoping to achieve a more elegant solution though. I will write a post myself to extend the answer I have offered in the **P.S.**.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\Phi=\sum_{i_1=0}^\infty \ldots \sum_{i_n=0}^\infty \phi_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}\prod_{j=1}^n x^{i_j}, \\
\Psi=\sum_{i_1=0}^\infty \ldots \sum_{i_n=0}^\infty \psi_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}\prod_{j=1}^n x^{i_j} 
.$$
Then 
$$
\Phi \cdot \Psi= \sum_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{\{a_s+b_s=i_s \}}\phi_{a_1,\ldots,a_n} \psi_{b_1,\ldots,b_n}\right)  \prod_{j=1}^n x^{i_j} 
$$

Comment: well, this is not wrong. But it is rather mathematical representation of the question. In other words, how one implement the $a_s+b_s=i_s$ part?